# Node.js + Coffeescript Class Inheritance with multiple exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, coffeescript

In Node.js and Coffeescript, I have defined a class, `Connector`, which inherits from Node's `EventEmitter`.

I want to define a subclass of `Connector`, called `Foo`.  When I try to define a new instance of `Foo`, I receive: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`.

I figure this is because I am not exporting the `Connector` class in my `module.exports`, but how can I both export my `_.tap()` function, as well as make the `Connector` class available to other classes as a parent class to extend?

```
# connectors.coffee
{ EventEmitter } = require 'events'
FS               = require 'fs'
Q                = require 'q'
_                = require 'underscore'
logger           = require './logger'

class Connector extends EventEmitter
  constructor: (@credential) ->

  name : 'Unnamed Connector'
  group: undefined

  search: (query) ->
    @_search(query)
    this

  _results: (results) ->
    @emit 'results', results

  _end: ->
    @emit 'end'

  _error: (error) ->
    @emit 'error', error

  module.exports = _.tap {}, (connectors) ->
    FS.readdirSync("#{__dirname}/connectors").forEach (file) ->
      # some logic


# foo.coffee
Connector = require '../connectors'
logger    = require '../logger'

class Foo extends Connector
  constructor: ->

  name: "test_connector"

  _search: (query) ->
    logger.info "Foo connector queried: #{query}"
    logger.info "Returning fake results, stand by"

module.exports = Foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it could be done like that (the order is important):

```
module.exports = _.tap {}, (connectors) ->
  #
  # your logic here
  #

module.exports.Connector = Connector

#i_use_tap.coffee
tapFunctionResult = require('../connectors')

#foo.coffee
Connector = require('../connectors').Connector
class Foo extends Connector
```